# Reverse for 'edit_post' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit_post/(?P<blog_id>\\d+)/$']

Tags: python, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGG66.png)the blog_post.html is working properly until the "edit post" link is passed , generating the error above , on the other hand it works if i removed the "blog_id" argument from the url pattern and "blog.id" from the "edit post" link ,but accordingly another error occurs when i click the "edit post" link and open the edit_post.html page it demands the missing (edit_post) argument , if i re-pass the argument again then the url patterns are not matching.

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'blogs'

urlpatterns = [
    #index
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),

    #make page for blogposts
    url(r'^blogposts/$',views.blogposts,name='blog_post'),

    #page for making a new post
    url(r'^new_post/$',views.make_post,name='add_post'),

    #page for editing post
    url(r'^edit_post//(?P<blog_id>\d+)$', views.edit_post, name = 'edit_post'),
]

the view page
    from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import BlogPost
from .forms import BlogPostForm
def edit_post(request,blog_id):
    post = BlogPost.objects.get(id=blog_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = BlogPostForm(instance = post)
    else:
        form = BlogPostForm(instance = post, data =request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blogs:blog_post'))
    context = {'post':post,'form':form}
    return render(request,'blogy/edit_post.html',context)



the page of the posts
 {% extends "blogy/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<p>The Posts:</p>
<ul>
    {% for blog in blogs %}
        <li>
            <p>{{ blog.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}</p>
            <p>{{ blog.text|linebreaks }}</p>
            <p>
                <a href = "{% url 'blogs:edit_post' %}">edit post</a>
            </p>
        </li>
        {% empty %}
        <li>no posts !</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
<a href="{% url 'blogs:add_post' %}">Add a new Post</a>
{% endblock content %}


the page where the edit post link goes
    {% extends "blogy/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<p>Edit Post:</p>
<form action = "{% url 'blogs:edit_post' blog.id %}" method = 'post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name='submit'>Save Changes</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You have double slash sign in edit post url.

Comment: The error is telling you that you are passing an empty string for the blog_id value. You need to show the template where you are generating that link, and the associated view.

Comment: Can you please show the file where you **reverse ** url?

Comment: @DevangPadhiar here are the rest of codes

Comment: @SergeyPugach yes thanks,edited it but not the issue

Comment: @DanielRoseman here are all the rest

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your url is waiting you to pass `blog_id` variable, but you pass nothing.
Here add `blog.id`

```
<a href = "{% url 'blogs:edit_post' blog_id=blog.id %}">edit post</a>
```

Comment: yes just did it ,comes this again ,,,,,,,,
Reverse for 'edit_post' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit_post/(?P<blog_id>\\d+)$'] and if no arguments passed in the url tag, it brings this ,,,,,,,,Reverse for 'edit_post' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit_post/(?P<blog_id>\\d+)$']

Comment: Try it with passing named argument `blog_id`. See edited answer.

Comment: sorry , but still the same ......Reverse for 'edit_post' with keyword arguments '{'blog_id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit_post/(?P<blog_id>\\d+)$']

Comment: In what url do you add it? Is that one in `for` loop while looping on blogs?

Comment: yes the whole url tag is within the loop, i have put an image in the description above , showing the blogpost page after removing the argument from the url tag and removing this ""/(?P<blog_id>\d+)"" from the url pattern as well, but if i click on the "edit post" link , it will the claim that the there is one argument (blog_id) missing for the edit_post function in views

Answer (score 0):

ok i realized the problem , it should have been (post.id) to be passed not (blog.id) because the name of the variable in the view function was rendered to the html page from the dictionary "context" with the name "post" not "blog"